# Need PouchDB errors list

Tags: pouchdb

I need errors list of pouchdb like:

```json
[
  { status: 409,
    name: 'conflict',
    message: 'Document update conflict',
    error: true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PouchDB is using [HTTP and Rest](https://pouchdb.com/guides/#http), so those error codes are actually **HTTP status codes**.

You should be able find the list of HTTP status codes including client errors (starting with 4xx) and server errors (starting with 5xx) on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) or the [W3C docs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).